# Android Socket Write Operation

Tags: android, sockets, exception

In my app i used socket read/write operation for server communication. When the server is off the socket write operation throws exception "pipeline broken" only at the second time. The first write operation doesn't throws any exception. Can anyone tell me the reason.

code i used for this is,

```
       SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(SERVERIP, 8080);
        Socket nsocket = new Socket();
        nsocket.setSoTimeout(3000);
        nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 5000); 
        if (nsocket.isConnected()) 
            { 
            mmInStream = nsocket.getInputStream();
            mmOutStream = nsocket.getOutputStream();
            }
```

code for write operation

```
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {          
    try {
        mmOutStream.write(buffer);
     } 
     catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There is only one reason for broken pipe errors. You have written to a connection that has already been closed by the other end. That in itself is an application protocol error, and it may have been caused by a prior application protocol error at this end, causing the peer to close the connection in exasperation.

Comment: The exception is thrown because i have stopped the server. My actual problem is that, exception is not thrown for the very first time i perform write operation after server is shut down. But it throws the exception the next time i tries to write.

Comment: @Unnnikrishnan PV that's basically due to buffering. Nothing you can do about it. You can't immediately detect a connection failure in TCP, it always takes a few seconds.